# Deploy docker container fails on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a simple application (docker) that I want to deploy through the AWS beanstalk.
U have a zip arhive with 2 files:

```
+simple.jar
+Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile contains these records:

```
FROM openjdk:11
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY ./ ./
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["java", "-jar", "simple.jar"]
```

I am getting this error during dpeloyment

```
[ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Run Docker Container]. Stop running the command. Error: open file failed with error open /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/.aws_beanstalk.current-container-id: no such file or directory
```

local build through "docker build" works and application is available on the port 80.

So I am not sure what to do and how to debug the problem more deeply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So problem was solved by changing the  Platform branch from
"Docker running on 64but Amazon Linux 2" to
"Docker running on 64but Amazon Linux".

It has different versions, but actually why it is not running needs more deep investigation.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue when my deployment had a ".ebextensions" directory. Removing the directory solved the issue.

[AWS Notes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html)

> On Amazon Linux 2 platforms, instead of providing files and commands in .ebextensions configuration files, we highly recommend that you use Buildfile. Procfile, and platform hooks whenever possible to configure and run custom code on your environment instances during instance provisioning. For details about these mechanisms, see Extending Elastic Beanstalk Linux platforms.